# set individual AWS S3 file/folder link to expire

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-sharing

I would like to share a file or folder in my AWS S3 bucket and set it to expire.
How do I do this within the S3 console?

Eg set it to public for 7 days then revert to private

Answer (score 1):

You can get a [signed url](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) to a private bucket object with a expiry time upto one week and share it with public users. The url will expire after the expiry limit making the object restricted again.

Comment: Agreed. Please note that this Pre-Signed URL is for one object only. It is not possible to share a 'folder' via this method.

Comment: thanks guys, how do I do this within the S3 console?

Comment: You can't in the console but here is an example in Java Or with the CLI http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html . http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html